# OOP : jQuery class method call on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am new to OOP in jQuery.

I have following class

```
/*
 * myClass
 */
var AlcoholOrder = function (options) {

    /*
     * Variables accessible
     * in the class
     */
    var vars = {
        myVar: 'original Value'
    };

    /*
     * Can access this.method
     * inside other methods using
     * root.method()
     */
    var root = this;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    this.construct = function (options) {
        $.extend(vars, options);
    };

    var addRemoveFavorite = function(){
        alert('function called');
    };

    $(function () {
        $(document.body).on('click', '.favorite-add', this.addRemoveFavorite);
    });

    /*
     * Pass options when class instantiated
     */
    this.construct(options);

};
```

Now I am initialising my class in one page with following code.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  var alcohol = new AlcoholOrder({ myVar : 'new Value' });
});
```

I want to call `addRemoveFavorite` method when click event fired. Currently when I click I am getting error

> jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError:
>   ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not
>   a function

I don't know how to call class method on click event. I have searched but not getting proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to jQuery. The trouble is that you're passing `undefined` as the event handler, because you defined `addRemoveFavorite` as a local variable, not an owned or inherited property. So `this.addRemoveFavorite` is not found, and `undefined` is substituted.

Comment: Ohh yes. that was my mistake. thanks @llama to guide me.